# PCRE regex to sed regex

Tags: regex, sed, pcre

First of all sorry for my bad english. I'm a german guy.

The code given below is working fine in PHP:

```
$string = preg_replace('/href="(.*?)(\.|\,)"/i','href="$1"',$string);
```

Now T need the same for `sed`. I thought it should be:

```
sed 's/href="(.*?)(\.|\,)"/href="{$\1}"/g' test.htm
```

But that gives me this error:

> sed: -e expression #1, char 36:
>   invalid reference \1 on `s' command's
>   RHS

Comment: What are you trying to do with this regex?

Comment: Can you clarify what you're trying to match and replace? I don't know PHP regexps as well as I know Linux ones.

Comment: PHP uses Perl Compatible Regular Expression (PCRE).

Comment: im trying to replace wrong urls that have a . or , at the end.

so <a href="http://www.blubb.de,"> should be replaced with <a href="http://www.blubb.de">

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sed -e 's|href=\"\(.[^"][^>]*\)\([.,]\)\">|href="\1">|g' file
```

Answer (score 3):

sed does not support non-greedy regex match.

Comment: Please elaborate on this matter.

Comment: \(.*?\) <--- this is greedy match.(with the question mark "?" )

Comment: So if sed does not support non-greedy match, it should support greedy match - What am I missing?

Comment: @Adam: OP is relying on non-greedy match for RE to work. The RE will most likely end up consuming characters past the end of the href attribute.

Comment: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Regular-Expressions check the "Quantifiers" subsection.

Answer (score 2):

You need a backslash in front of the parentheses you want to reference, thus

```
sed 's/href="\(.*?\)(.|\,)"/href="{$\1}"/g' test.htm
```

Comment: you didn't say what you want to do, just that the regexp failed :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to escape the block selector characters `(` and `)` as follows.

```
sed 's/href="\(.*?\)\(.|\,\)"/href="{$\1}"/g' test.htm
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to match a literal ".", you need to escape it or use it in a character class. As an alternative to slashing the capturing parentheses (which you need to do with basic REs), you can use the -E option to tell sed to use extended REs. Lastly, the REs used by sed use `\N` to refer to subpatterns, where `N` is a digit.

```
sed -E "s/href=([\"'])([^\"']*)[.,]\1/href=\1\2\1/i"
```

This has its own issue that will prevent matches of href attributes that use both types of quotes.

`man sed` and `man re_format` will give more information on REs as used in sed.

Comment: In my version of sed, it uses `-r` to specify extended regular expressions (which do not require escaping parenthesis) instead of `-E`.

Answer (score 0):

here is a solution, it is not prefect, only deal with the situation of one extra "," or "."

```
sed -r -e 's/href="([^"]*)([.,]+)"/href="\1"/g' test.htm
```