# What's wrong with my lookahead regex in GNU sed?

Tags: regex, linux, sed, regex-lookarounds

This is what I'm doing (simplified example):

```
gsed -i -E 's/^(?!foo)(.*)$/bar\1/' file.txt
```

I'm trying to put `bar` in front of every line that doesn't start with `foo`. This is the error:

```
gsed: -e expression #1, char 22: Invalid preceding regular expression
```

What's wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2086450/pcre-regex-to-sed-regex

Comment: please update  the chosen answer if possible. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12178023/131120) shows that it's actually possible to achieve the same with sed.

Comment: I disagree with that. I was looking for how to do a lookahead with sed and the answer to that question is: you can't

Answer (score 76, accepted):

As far as I know `sed` has not neither look-ahead nor look-behind. Switch to a more powerful language with similar syntax, like `perl`.

Comment: A simple `sed` to `perl` conversion for reference: `sed 's/before/after/g' /my/file` => `cat /my/file | perl -ne 's/before/after/g; print;'`

Comment: @Batandwa The use of cat and piping into perl is redundant. Just use `perl -pi -e 's/before/after/g' /my/file`.

Comment: It's quite unfortunate that there is no lookahead.

Comment: I think this is a wrong answer: `sed` has this capabilities supplying multiple editing sequences, as kkeller answer.

Comment: @Cirelli94: While this is a nice recommendation, that's not negative lookahead as in regular (pun intended) regex syntax.

Comment: I appreciate the perl solution - perl has always just been the better solution, even if its just for the PCRE.  Having said (sed?) that, in the year 2024, why hasn't sed implemented a PCRE flag????

Answer (score 175):

```
sed -i '/^foo/! s/^/bar/' file.txt
```

- `-i` change the file in place
- `/^foo/!` only perform the next action on lines not `!` starting with *foo* `^foo`
- `s/^/bar/` change the start of the line to bar

Comment: Very nice solution. No need for back tracking. Just use functionality that sed already has.

Comment: This is fine for an anchored expression like `^foo`, but unfortunately doesn't extend to the general case of negative lookahead anywhere in a pattern.

Comment: It does, however, extend when only one instance of the replacement exists in the line. For example, `'s/(?!foo)baz/bar/'` =>`'/foobaz/! s/baz/bar/'`. Perhaps a proper application of cleverness can extend this approach to lines containing, e.g., "foobaz baz".

Comment: @tripleee It is possible. Check [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/487725/sed-replace-word-except-when-word-is-preceded-by-a-specific-string/487758#487758) for ideas.

Comment: @WeijunZhou Replacing the `foobaz` string with a unique string which doesn't occur anywhere in the input (which is feasible with a randomized string if it's long enough), then replacing the remaining `baz`es, then replacing back the unique string with `foobaz` is, again, a workaround which only works when the negative lookahead is a static string.

Comment: If it is a fixed-length(which is required for lookbehind anyway) string pattern you can still embed the original string in the intermediate string so that the information is not lost and can be recovered later.

Comment: What if I needed to delete the line? This did not work for me: sed '/foo/! /bar/d' file.txt

Comment: @Nabheet: I'm not sure what lines you want deleted. Your code says "search lines which do not contain foo" and then, instead of giving a command, saying what to do with those lines, you give another filter. That can not work.

If you want to delete all lines which do not contain foo, then use '/foo/! d'

If you want to delete all lines which do not contain foo but do contain bar, then you need a block command after the first filter to apply a second filter: '/foo/! {/bar/d}'

And beware, the original question was about lines starting with foo, you dropped that by removing the ^

Comment: Awesome thanks! you just confirmed what I ended up implementing. Not sure how I ended up here but it was a lot of trial and error. I ended up with this /match_a/{/match_b/!d}. I needed "search lines for match_a, only delete line if it does NOT contain match_b." This is really cool and I didn't need any regex lookarounds. Thank you!

Answer (score 12):

You use perl compatible regular expression (PCRE) syntax which is not supported by GNU sed.
You should rewrite your regex according to SED [Regular-Expressions](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Regular-Expressions.html) or use `perl` instead.

Note that SED doesn't have lookahead and therefore doesn't support the regex feature you were trying to use. It can be done in SED using other features, as others have mentioned.