# reuse last matched character of regex in sed

Tags: regex, sed

Many of you with a certain leaning towards proper formatting will know the pain of having a lot of space characters insted of a tab character in the beginning of indented lines after another person edited a file and added lines. I seem to be unable to teach my colleagues how to use vim's integrated line pasting function, so I'm searching for some simple ways to automatically correct lines beginning with a certain pattern. ;)

I'm using a regex to find the corresponding lines, but I can't work out how to "reuse" the last matched character in sed when using "find and replace". The regex matching the lines is

```
'^\ *[A-Z]'
```

I would like to replace those space characters, but keep the uppercase letter. My idea would be something like

```
sed 's|^\ *[A-Z]|\t$|g'
```

or so, but I guess that would replace the whole line with a single tab character since `$` usually matches the line ending?

Is there a simple way to reuse parts of the matched regex in sed?

Comment: Yes, capture groups. (\parens around the group, reference by \1 on the right.)

Comment: Could you provide more information and a little example as an answer please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about simply not including the first non-space character in the match in the first place?

This matches all spaces at the beginning of a line:

```
^ *
```

Edit (quote from the comments):

> obviously I don't want to replace spaces in front of other characters than uppercase letters

A look-ahead could do that, but unfortunatey sed does not support them. But you can use the next best thing, an expression that determines which lines sed operates on:

```
sed '|^ *[A-Z]| s|^ *|\t|'
```

Of course a back-reference would do it as well:

```
sed 's|^ *\([A-Z]\)|\t\1|'
```

Comment: I know that, but obviously I don't want to replace spaces in front of other characters than uppercase letters. Thanks though.^^

Comment: @David: No problem. sed can use preconditions: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12178023/18771, just use `/^ *[A-Z]/` as your's.

Comment: That's what I call "escaping voodoo" - escaping characters "just to be sure". The space is not a special character in regular expressions, there is no need to escape it, unless the specific environment (e.g. shell) requires it for other reasons.