# How can I use sed to find a line starting with AAA but NOT end with BBB

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I'm trying to create a script to append *oracleserver* to */etc/hosts* as an alias of *localhost*. Which means I need to:

1. Locate the line that `^127.0.0.1` and **NOT** `oracleserver$`
2. Then, append `oracleserver` to this line

I know the best practice is probably using *negative look ahead*. However, *sed* does not have look around feature: [What's wrong with my lookahead regex in GNU sed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12176026/whats-wrong-with-my-lookahead-regex-in-linux-sed). Can anyone provide me some possible solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sed -i '/oracleserver$/! s/^127\.0\.0\.1.*$/& oracleserver/' filename
```

- `/oracleserver$/!` - on lines not ending with *oracleserver*
- `^127\.0\.0\.1.*$` - replace the whole line if it is starting with *127.0.0.1*
- `& oracleserver` - with the line plus a space separator `' '` (required) and `oracleserver` after that

Comment: Can you explain a little bit about the dot in your solution?

Comment: @lifeGoGoGo, see my update. Dots mean one character.

Answer (score 2):

Just use awk with `&&` to combine the two conditions:

```
awk '/^127\.0\.0\.1/ && !/oracleserver$/ { $0 = $0 "oracleserver" } 1' file
```

This appends the string when the first pattern is matched but the second one isn't. The `1` at the end is always *true*, so awk prints each line (the default action is `{ print }`).

Comment: This also works. But since @ndn gave the sed solution :)

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use `sed` but instead `perl`:

Locate the line that ^127.0.0.1 and NOT oracleserver$

```
perl -pe 'if ( m/^127\.0\.0\.1/ and not m/oracleserver$/ ) { s/$/oracleserver/ }'
```

Should do the trick. You can add `-i.bak` to inplace edit too.

Comment: If you are going to use perl, why not `perl -pe -i 's/^(127\.0\.0\.1.*)(?<!oracleserver)$/\1oracleserver/g filename`?

Comment: Because I don't like trying to compress all my code into a regular expression unless it is essential.