# How to match a string not followed by a word using sed

Tags: regex, sed

I need to delete all strings consisting of a hyphen followed by a whitespace, but only when the whitespace is not followed by the word "og".
Example file:

```
Kultur- og idrettsavdelinga skapar nyska- pande kunst og utvik- lar samfunnet
```

I tried negative lookahead :

```
sed -e 's/- (?!og)//g'
```

but it doesn't work. What I want is something like this:

```
Kultur- og idrettsavdelinga skapar nyskapande kunst og utviklar samfunnet.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: AFAIK, `sed` do not have support for lookaheads and lookbehinds.. **[source](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12176026/whats-wrong-with-my-lookahead-regex-in-gnu-sed)** ..you can use `perl` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given this input file (I added `- eller`s since you said in a comment you need to handle them too):

```
$ cat file
Kultur- og idrettsavdelinga skapar- eller nyska- pande kunst og utvik- lar- eller samfunnet
```

here's the common sed idiomatic approach:

```
$ sed 's/a/aA/g; s/- og/aB/g; s/- eller/aC/g; s/- //g; s/aC/- eller/g; s/aB/- og/g; s/aA/a/g' file
Kultur- og idrettsavdelinga skapar- eller nyskapande kunst og utviklar- eller samfunnet
```

The above works by turning all `a`s (or whatever other char you like that's not in your target strings) into `aA` so we can then turn the strings we're interested in, `- og` and `- eller`, into `a<some other character>`, e.g. `aB` and `aC` and at that point we **know** the only occurrences of `aB` and `aC` in the input are the newly transformed `- og` and `- eller` since all of the existing `a`s are now `aA`.

Now we can just remove all remaining `-`s from the file and then convert the `aC`s back to `- eller` and `aB`s back to `- og`s and finally all `aA`s back to the original `a`s.

Answer (score 1):

The lookahead feature isn't available with sed, but you can describe all possibilities:

```
sed -e 's/\(- \(- \)*\)\([^o]\|$\|o\([^g]\|$\)\)/\3/g'
```

You can test it with: `- - - - og - - oa - o` => `- og oa o`

Comment: That'll work for `og` ("and" in Norwegian), but he'll probably also need to look for `eller` ("or") as well...

Comment: You're right about that! I need to look for "eller" as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a *sed chain*, first replacing `- og` with something nonsensical (like `booogabooga`), then performing the replacement, then reversing the `booogabooga`.

```
sed -e 's/- og/booogabooga/g; s/- //g; s/booogabooga/- og/g'
```

Some versions of *sed* may need:

```
sed -e 's/- og/booogabooga/g' -e 's/- //g' -e 's/booogabooga/- og/g'
```

This can be slower and more painful, especially if you have multiple replacements as @Kusalananda suggests, but it is easier to understand.

Comment: The safe, idiomatic approach is to create a string (or strings) that can't exist in the input, not try to guess one. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/38153467/1745001.

Comment: @EdMorton true. Now that I Google it, there are incredibly [174 results for "booogabooga"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22booogabooga%22) which I thought I just made up.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately it's not even 100% safe to use `$'\n'` as the temp replacement string in case someones using hold space/buffer/time warp voodoo conjurations to force sed to do multi-line stuff.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's/(- (og|eller))|- /\1/g' file
```

This relies on alternation to re-replace specific cases and the empty backreference to replace the general case.