# Sed - How to replace first character based on next 2 characters

Tags: bash, sed

I want to remove ";" from line if it is not followed by "number" + "=" sign.
e.g.

```
echo "32=rtys;54tyu;45_fd;62=xyz;fdg"
output should be "32=rtys54tyu45_fd;62=xyzfdg"
```

I tried below but it worked only for letters.

```
sed 's/;\($\|[^[:digit:]=]\)/\1/g'
```

but it only works for ;+letters and not others.

Comment: In the title you say "based on next 2 characters" but in your example the thing you're calling a "number" seems to be a 2-digit number, so the algorithm seems to depend on more than the next two characters.

Comment: Your example does not match with your conditions.

Comment: use a pattern match in the address expression to match the lines you want to do a replacement on.

Answer (score 2):

#### Using sed

```
$ s="32=rtys;54tyu;45_fd;62=xyz;fdg"
$ sed -E 's/;/\n/g; s/\n[0-9]+=/;&/g; s/\n//g' <<<"$s"
32=rtys54tyu45_fd;62=xyzfdg
```

This works in three steps:

1. `s/;/\n/g` replaces all semicolons with newlines.  Because, by default, sed takes input one line at a time, the pattern space will never have a newline to start.  Thus will be no confusion.
2. `s/\n[0-9]+=/;&/g` puts a semicolon in front of any newline followed by a number followed by an equal sign.
3. `s/\n//g` removes all newlines.

The above was tested on GNU sed.  For BSD/OSX, some changes will likely be needed.  The following might work:

```
sed -E $'s/;/\n/g; s/\n[0-9]+=/;&/g; s/\n//g' <<<"$s"
```

#### Using awk

```
$ s="32=rtys;54tyu;45_fd;62=xyz;fdg"
$ awk -F\; '{$1=$1; for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) if ($i~/^[0-9]+=/) $i=";"$i} 1' OFS="" <<<"$s"
32=rtys54tyu45_fd;62=xyzfdg
```

This works by using `;` as the field separator on input and the empty string as a field separator on output.  This would remove all `;` except that we check each field: if a field begins with number+`=`, we add a semicolon to the beginning of that field.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ sed -E 's/a/aA/g; s/;([0-9]+=)/aB\1/g; s/;//g; s/aB/;/g; s/aA/a/g' file
32=rtys54tyu45_fd;62=xyzfdg
```

This is a common, idiomatic approach - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/38153467/1745001 for an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Easy to do with negative lookahead:

```
$ echo "32=rtys;54tyu;45_fd;62=xyz;fdg" | perl -pe 's/;(?!\d+=)//g'
32=rtys54tyu45_fd;62=xyzfdg
```

- `;(?!\d+=)` means `;` not followed by one or more digits and `=`