# PCRE Regex to SED

Tags: regex, sed, pcre

I am trying to take PCRE regex and use it in SED, but I'm running into some issues. Please note that this question is representative of a bigger issue (how to convert PCRE regex to work with SED) so the question is not simply about the example below, but about how to use PCRE regex in SED regex as a whole.

This example is extracting an email address from a line, and replacing it with "[emailaddr]".

```
echo "My email is abc@example.com" | sed -e 's/[a-zA-Z0-9]+[@][a-zA-Z0-9]+[\.][A-Za-z]{2,4}/[emailaddr]/g'
```

I've tried the following replace regex:

```
([a-zA-Z0-9]+[@][a-zA-Z0-9]+[\.][A-Za-z]{2,4})
[a-zA-Z0-9]+[@][a-zA-Z0-9]+[\.][A-Za-z]{2,4}
([a-zA-Z0-9]+[@][a-zA-Z0-9]+[.][A-Za-z]{2,4})
[a-zA-Z0-9]+[@][a-zA-Z0-9]+[.][A-Za-z]{2,4}
```

I've tried changing the delimited of sed from s/find/replace/g to s|find|replace|g as outlined [here (stack overflow: pcre regex to sed regex)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2086450/pcre-regex-to-sed-regex).

I am still not able to figure out how to use PCRE regex in SED, or how to convert PCRE regex to SED. Any help would be great.

Comment: Note that `.` is not special in `[brackets]`, so you don't have to escape it: `[.]` is fine. Also, `@` is not special in regular expressions at all, so you don't need to put it in brackets (unless you like the way it looks)

Comment: Just a tip, you know you can use perl in a very similar to sed (syntax wise)  and of course it suppors PCRE `perl -pe 's/oldstring/newstring/'`

Comment: -1 Your question is wrong and you never corrected it.   Also, a program (not sed), has been written that supports PCRE and changes in text files, from the command line http://superuser.com/questions/339118/regex-replace-from-command-line

Comment: The regexes in the question do not use any feature of PCRE which is not in ERE. So they are just extended regular expressions (ERE). Many modern `sed` implementations support ERE - even the specification in the POSIX draft describes the option as `sed -E`.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Use the `-r` flag enabling the use of [extended regular expressions](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Extended-regexps). ( `-E` instead of `-r` on **OS X** )

```
echo "My email is abc@example.com" | sed -r 's/[a-zA-Z0-9]+@[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}/[emailaddr]/g'
```

[Ideone Demo](http://ideone.com/79tJK6)

Comment: I get 'sed: illegal option -- r'

Comment: Nevermind, its just a weird Mac thing. Works on my linux box so im set. Thank you so much!

Comment: On the Mac, you want `-E` instead: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/sed.1.html

Comment: Note that `-E` works with GNU `sed` too (as an undocumented alias of `-r`).

Comment: Thats great to know. I thought my regex was wrong. I didnt even think that the regex wasnt even being parsed.

Comment: Are extended regular expressions (via the -r switch) the same thing as Perl Compatible Regular Expressions (PCRE, per the question)?

Comment: -1  and @AlexHall  no they are not the same thing, this answer is misleading(for not addressing PCRE in the title). .  PCRE (last time I checked), is not supported in SED. The most SED supports is ERE(extended...)  (which requires the sed -r), without -r it's just BRE(basic...).   Sed doesn't support PCRE. Grep does(with -P), but not sed.   The question is misleading too since while the title says PCRE, the regex only requires ERE

Comment: `-E` should be certainly preferred. Modern implementations of `sed` (including GNU sed) follow the current POSIX draft and support ERE using `sed -E`. As barlop has already said the question contains just ERE regexes no need for PCRE here.

Answer (score 44):

Want PCRE (***P**erl **C**ompatible **R**egular **E**xpressions*)? Why don't you use `perl` instead?

```
perl -pe 's/[a-zA-Z0-9]+[@][a-zA-Z0-9]+[\.][A-Za-z]{2,4}/[emailaddr]/g' \
    <<< "My email is abc@example.com"
```

Output:

```
My email is [emailaddr]
```

Write output to a file with `tee`:

```
perl -pe 's/[a-zA-Z0-9]+[@][a-zA-Z0-9]+[\.][A-Za-z]{2,4}/[emailaddr]/g' \
    <<< "My email is abc@example.com" | tee /path/to/file.txt > /dev/null
```

Comment: This is a really good point about using perl. This works great when we are not processing large amounts of data and speed is not important. Because sed is fast. Like really fast!

Comment: @cherio and you think Perl is slow? Have you done any measurements? You won't notice too much of a difference. Because Perl is fast. Like really fast.

Comment: On a Core i7-2600 under Ubuntu/WSL2, using the "extended regex" `"s/to_date\(('.{19}'),'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'\)/CONVERT(DATETIME,\1,120)/g"` on a 100 MB file, perl substantially outperforms sed -E and runs approximately 10 times faster.

Comment: "Don't have Perl and want to use PCRE, why don't you just use Perl?"
I'm sorry, but this is oen of the most classic non-answer I've seen in a while.

Answer (score 10):

GNU sed uses [basic regular expressions](https://www.gnu.org/software/gnulib/manual/html_node/ed-regular-expression-syntax.html#ed-regular-expression-syntax) or, with the `-r` flag, [extended regular expressions](https://www.gnu.org/software/gnulib/manual/html_node/posix_002dextended-regular-expression-syntax.html#posix_002dextended-regular-expression-syntax).

Your regex as a POSIX basic regex (thanks mklement0):

```
[[:alnum:]]\{1,\}@[[:alnum:]]\{1,\}\.[[:alpha:]]\{2,4\}
```

Note that this expression will **not** match all email addresses (not by a long shot).

Comment: Since the OP also seems to use OS X: note that `sed` there (FreeBSD `sed`) uses _POSIX_ basic regexes, where `\+` and `\?` are _not_ supported - use `\{1,\}` and `\{0,1\}` instead.

Comment: Thats also good to know. I'm in a tough spot because my dev machine is OSX and prod machine is linux.... But I'll keep that in mind. Thanks

Comment: @Sugitime: If you find yourself having to use both  GNU `sed` and FreeBSD `sed` regularly, here's a summary of the differences: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24276470/45375

Answer (score 2):

for multiline use the 0!
perl -0pe 's/search/replace/gms' file

Answer (score 0):

*Sometimes* this might be helpful too as a work-around:

```
str=$(grep -Poh "pcre-pattern" file)
sed -i "s/$str/$something_else/" file
```

> -o, --only-matching:
>                 Print only the matched (non-empty) parts of a matching  line,  with  each such part on a separate output line.