# Change variable evaluation method in all script from $VAR_NAME to ${VAR_NAME}

Tags: linux, bash

We have couple of scripts where we want to replace variable evaluation method from `$VAR_NAME` to `${VAR_NAME}`
This is required so that scripts will have uniform method for variable evaluation

I am thinking of using `sed` for the same, I wrote sample command which looks like follows,

```
echo "\$VAR_NAME" | sed 's/^$[_a-zA-Z0-9]*/${&}/g'
```

output for the same is

```
${$VAR_NAME}
```

Now i don't want `$` inside `{}`, how can i remove it?
Any better suggestions for accomplishing this task?

**EDIT**
Following command works

```
echo "\$VAR_NAME" | sed -r 's/\$([_a-zA-Z]+)/${\1}/g'
```

**EDIT1**
I used following command to do replacement in script file

```
sed -i -r 's:\$([_a-zA-Z0-9]+):${\1}:g' <ScriptName>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the first part of your `sed` command searches for the `$` and `VAR_NAME`, the whole `$VAR_NAME` part will be put inside the `${}` wrapper.

You could search for the `$` part with a lookbehind in your regular expression, so that you end up ending the `sed` call with `/{&}/g` as the `$` will be to the left of your matched expression.

http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html 
http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=518444

I don't think `sed` supports this kind of regular expression, but you can make a command that begins `perl -pe` instead.  I believe the following perl command may do what you want.

```
perl -p -e 's/(?<=\$)[_a-zA-Z0-9]*/{$&}/g'
```

[PCRE Regex to SED](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24832458/pcre-regex-to-sed#comment38558203_24832458)

Comment: how do we search `$` part with lookbehind in `sed`, any idea ?

Comment: I found one solution using sed `sed -r 's/\$([_a-zA-Z]+)/${\1}/g'`