# remove \r\n from within double quoted field in csv file

Tags: csv

I have a large csv file with about 100 double quoted "text fields" per line. Many of the lines have a \r\n embedded in a double quoted field. The \r\n pair is also used for line termination.

How can the \r\n pairs be removed from the double quoted fields and not impact the \r\n line terminations.

I have tried creating individual sed scripts to identify the particular embedded sequences. That sort of worked, but the number of scripts became unmanageable. I have also tried using a 'tr -d '\r' command, that did not work.

Answer (score 1):

For this purpose you can use `perl`.

```sh
perl -0pe 's/"(.*?)([[:space:]]+)(.*?)"/"\1 \3"/g' input.csv > output.csv
```

`perl -pe 's/../../g' file` is analogous to `sed -e 's/../../g' file`  but using [Perl compatible regular expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl_Compatible_Regular_Expressions)  (PCRE). See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24832458/pcre-regex-to-sed) or [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1096208/1465124)  for more details.

With the option *zero*   `perl -0`  we are considering the *null character* as input record separator (see `xargs -0 ...`  or `find . -print0 ...`).

All versions of `sed` supports [Basic Regular Expressions](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/basedefs/xbd_chap09.html#tag_09_03) (BRE) and some versions, as *GNU sed*  (using `sed -E`), supports [Extended Regular Expressions](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/sed-regular-expressions.html#sed-regular-expressions) (ERE), a superset of BRE.  Both in BRE and ERE the quantifiers `*` and  `+` are always greedy, they match as many characters as possible. In some contexts, however, we need to match as few characters as possible. With PCRE we can do the quantifiers `*` and `+`  *[lazy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Lazy_matching)* or *minimal* or *reluctant* using  `*?` and  `+?`  respectively.

In order to remove `\r\n` inside double quotes preserving any other line break, we use *lazy matching*: `"(.*?)([[:space:]]+)(.*?)"`. We also use [backreferences](https://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html) `"\1 \3"`  omitting the second matched parentheses which contains any sequence of  *white spaces* (characters `\t`,`\r`, `\n`, `\v` or `\f`), in particular sequences of `\r\n`.

This approach works in CSV files in which "*lines have **a** `\r\n` embedded in a double quoted field*" as is your case. If `input.csv`  contains cells with three or more paragraphs separated by `\r\n`, we must modify the regular expression.